# Spring Data - FindOne or HTML Hidden Input

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

"Hidden input or findOne(id)?" --- > This is a big dilemma for me when i need update anything.

What is the best thing to do:

- use hidden input and load with entity attribute (this case user can modify the data)?
- find the object by id (findOne(id)), in other words, call spring data to retrive a data from bd (this case is heavy to get data)?

So... What you think about? What is your opinion?

Comment: _So... What should i do?_ That depends on what you want to achieve. I think no one in here will understand what you are trying to ask...

Comment: What have you tried?  Or do you just want an opinion based answer to point you in the right direction?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald i already tried both, but no one makes me satisfied...

Comment: Please, dont negative it! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about security, I choose findOne(id).

Thinking about performace, I choose hidden(id).

Thinking about best choice, I choose customFindOne(id)